# Can I use Cloud Dataproc with an external Hive Metastore?

Tags: hive, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-dataproc, hive-metastore

By default, [Cloud Dataproc](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc) runs a Hive Metastore local to the Dataproc cluster. This means:

1. The metastore is ephemeral with the cluster
2. It can be a pain to have multiple clusters using a single metastore

Is it possible to point Dataproc clusters to a single Hive metastore? Is it also possible to have the metastore live outside the cluster so running a cluster for a metastore is not required?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible - clusters can use a common metastore running on [Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql).

Cloud Dataproc clusters can use this [Cloud SQL Proxy](https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/initialization-actions/tree/master/cloud-sql-proxy) to connect to the external SQL metastore. Before using this solution, you should review the [important notes](https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/initialization-actions/tree/master/cloud-sql-proxy#important-notes-for-hive-metastore).