# Can multiple GCP Dataproc clusters use same metastore?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc, hive-metastore

Planning to use Dataproc cluster with Dataproc Metastore.

Questions:

- when we delete Dataproc clusters, would Dataproc Metastore continue to remain available?
- Can two different Dataproc clusters in same region, use same Dataproc Metastore?
- Can two different Dataproc clusters on different region, use same Dataproc Metastore?

Comment: Yes to all 3 questions.

Comment: here in this post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60494168/can-i-use-cloud-dataproc-with-an-external-hive-metastore) it was mentioned that "The metastore is ephemeral with the cluster". So just to confirm, would both the dataproc metastore and metadata would continue to be available even after dataproc cluster deletion?

Comment: By default there is an in-cluster metastore, which will be deleted with the cluster. But you can use an external metastore, which is independent of the cluster lifecycle. Dataproc Metastore Service is the recommended solution https://cloud.google.com/dataproc-metastore/docs, but you can also setup your own metastore with Cloud SQL https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/initialization-actions/tree/master/cloud-sql-proxy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Posting this as a community wiki:

As what Dagang said, the answer is to use an external metastore that persists outside of the cluster lifecycle. You can do this in two ways:

Using [Dataproc Metastore Service](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc-metastore/docs)

Using [Cloud SQL proxy](https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/initialization-actions/tree/master/cloud-sql-proxy)